# got 'VerifyError' when Mock in Spock1.1

Tags: spring, groovy, spock, cglib, verifyerror

when i try to mock a spring service, i got `verifyError`. i have check spock version and groovy version, it's seens no problem. can somebody point me how to resovle this issue ? Thanks!

- Spock version: spock-core-1.1-groovy-2.4-rc-3.jar
- Groovy version: groovy-all-2.4.6.jar
- Cglib version: cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar

  java.lang.VerifyError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method visit.(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.(AbstractClassGenerator.java:38)
  at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.(KeyFactory.java:127)
  at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:112)
  at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
  at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
  at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.(Enhancer.java:69)
  at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory$CglibMockFactory.createMock(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:144)
  at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory.create(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:66)
  at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockFactory.createInternal(JavaMockFactory.java:59)
  at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockFactory.create(JavaMockFactory.java:40)
  at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CompositeMockFactory.create(CompositeMockFactory.java:44)
  at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMock(SpecInternals.java:45)
  at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:281)
  at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.MockImpl(SpecInternals.java:99)
  at com.example.apiimpl.query.UserAccountAuthQueryServiceSpec.setup(UserAccountAuthQueryServiceSpec.groovy:86)

Answer (score 1):

cglib is no longer actively maintained and it has some problems dealing with newer byte code. Spock is capable of using Byte Buddy for code generation if you use a newer version. Just put it on the class path for using it.